# Collage of six photos, not Facebook Lookback movie

Tags: facebook, facebook-lookback

I didn't get a Facebook look back movie. I've been on Facebook since it was “thefacebook” in 2005 and I've shared my little heart out.

Anybody know if the automated video is linked to security settings or other things that might be locking me out?

I get the lame collage of 6 pictures that were all posted in the last week. No, thanks. I'd rather have a movie.

Comment: Did you delete any post after watching the video?

Comment: Even if the video is not generating, you think it will work later?

Comment: Related: [Facebook Look Back video](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/56590/7584)

Comment: To further investigate this issue: In [Settings » Apps » Apps others use](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=friends_share&view), is 'My Photos' and 'My Videos' checked?

Answer (score 3):

The videos are generated on the fly and considering the amount of users watching/generating, the share link may or may not appear.

Give it some time & come back again, the link should be up