# Facebook Lookback Video

Tags: facebook, facebook-lookback

Am I the only one who hasn't got a look back video at all? Every time I click the link for it, it just brings up photos for me. I'm kinda getting annoyed because everyone else is getting one and I'm the only one so far who seems to be having this problem.

Anyone any ideas on what I can do or if there is anything I can do?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate,I posted this as I had a query about it myself. This may be questioning the same thing but is worded different,hardly a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Facebook Help Center article on Facebook Look Back, "[Why am I not seeing a movie?](https://www.facebook.com/help/661024940630042)":

> If you aren’t seeing A Look Back movie when you visit [facebook.com/lookback](https://www.facebook.com/lookback), it may be because you have not shared very many things on Facebook. Depending on how long you’ve been on Facebook and how much you’ve shared, you’ll see a movie, a collection of photos or a thank you card.

Comment: I saw that,but i've been on it since 2009 and constantly post pictures and statuses etc I share a lot of things aswell.There's people from 2011 getting one.

Comment: @Rachel To further investigate this issue: In your [Facebook Settings » Apps » Apps others use](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=friends_share&view), is 'My Photos' and 'My Videos' checked?

Comment: I also don't have a video.  I don't share much and I don't upload photos so I guess this answer explains why I don't have one.